# MockRestServiceServer changing request factory

Tags: resttemplate, spring-test

I am unable to get my tests to run because MockRestServiceServer changes the requestfactory so doing the following doesn't work.

```
restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory(new AcceptAllHostnameVerifier()));
mockRestServiceServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);
```

This is the source constructor:

```
    public static MockRestServiceServer createServer(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
    Assert.notNull(restTemplate, "'restTemplate' must not be null");

    MockRestServiceServer mockServer = new MockRestServiceServer();
    RequestMatcherClientHttpRequestFactory factory = mockServer.new RequestMatcherClientHttpRequestFactory();

    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(factory);

    return mockServer;
```

Is there anyway to set the request factory on MockRestServiceServer so my tests will run?